# Compact nested for loops

Tags: r, nested-loops, python-itertools

The following is Python code. How can the same be done in R?

Code:

```
from itertools import product 

mean_ops      = ['Zero', 'Constant', 'AR'] 

variance_ops  = ['arch', 'garch', 'gjr', 'figarch', 'aparch', 'har']

dist_ops    = ['normal', 't', 'skewt', 'ged']


for mean, variance, dist in product(mean_ops, variance_ops, dist_ops):
```

Output:

```
Zero arch normal
Zero arch t
Zero arch skewt
Zero arch ged
Zero garch normal
Zero garch t
Zero garch skewt
Zero garch ged
Zero gjr normal
Zero gjr t
Zero gjr skewt
```

In total there are 72 combinations (3 mean_opc X 6 variance_opc X 4 dist_opc).

Comment: The `expand.grid()` function creates a dataframe holding the results.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function that will answer this question in general. Since R works well with vectors, instead of using a `for` loop we'll create your final 72-item character vector by creating three temporary vectors--one for each input variable--and then paste them together element-wise to get the output.

The trick is to repeat each element of your three inputs the right number of times in the right order. I've done it here using `lapply()`, and then used the `%>%` pipe operator to `unlist()` the results back to basic character vectors. This is just for readability, and you could easily do it without the pipe.

```
library(magrittr)

mean_ops <- c('Zero', 'Constant', 'AR') 
variance_ops <- c('arch', 'garch', 'gjr', 'figarch', 'aparch', 'har')
dist_ops <- c('normal', 't', 'skewt', 'ged')

get_combinations <- function(x1, x2, x3){
  
  x1_reps <- lapply(x1, rep, times = length(x2) * length(x3)) %>%
    unlist()
  
  x2_reps <- lapply(x2, rep, times = length(x3)) %>%
    unlist() %>%
    rep(times = length(x1))
  
  x3_reps <- rep(x3, length(x1) * length(x2))
  
  return(paste(x1_reps, x2_reps, x3_reps))
}

get_combinations(mean_ops, variance_ops, dist_ops)
```